# Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I'm relatively new to javascript OOP, and have what I believe is a relatively basic question but I haven't been able to find any help through searching the web. Am I missing something or am I simply going about this the wrong way?

Here's my example code:

```
function Square( setSize, setX, setY ){
  var size = setSize;
  var xPos = setX;
  var yPos = setY;

  this.getCenter = function(){
    return {
      x: xPos + size*0.5,
      y: yPos + size*0.5
    };
  };

  this.moveX = function( magnitude ){

    var currentPosition //=how do I access getCenter() from here?

  };

}
```

Comment: read [`this`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/pseudo-classical-pattern#pseudo-class-declaration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the current object; it's not implicit, like in other languages, mainly because the function is just an object like any other and its `this` can be bound to any value.

```
var currentPosition = this.getCenter();
```